# How to select by fields in preloaded object?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I wonder if it is possible to select by a condition in a preloaded object. For example, I have tables User and Profile (one to one). So I need to get all Users with Profiles where sex is female.

I thought it can be done by something like this:

```
Preload("UserProfile").Where("user_profile.sex = ?", "female")
```

But it returns something like:

> pq: missing FROM-clause entry for table \"user_profile\"

Comment: I belive the table is actually called `user_profiles`

Comment: I found, I have to use Joints: Joins("left join trade_items on trade_items.id = trade_requests.trade_item_id") and then Where("trade_items.request_type = ?", "SELL")

Answer (score 1):

Preloading doesn't join the tables specified. You need to explicitly join the table in question:

```golang
Preload("UserProfile").Joins("LEFT JOIN user_profile ON user.id = user_profile.user_id")
    .Where("user_profile.sex = ?", "female")
```

...Assuming your primary key is called `id`, and foreign key is called `user_id`.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue in a recent project. I found the below solution to work for me.

```
var users []User
Preload("UserProfile","sex = ?","female").Find(&users)
```

and then check for

```
user.profile!=nil
```

The issue in this approach is it will load all users.

But in your case, it can be another way around.

```
var profiles []Profile
Preload("User").where("sex = ?","female").Find(&profiles)
```

I hope this will solve your problem.